# Animation between two UIViews

Tags: ios

```
    view=[[UIView alloc]init];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                       forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.view addSubview:view.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

i AM using this but i want animation like two Navigation Controllers.
I am using two UIViews.

Comment: will you tell me why vote down.

Comment: Because that's not a question. That's a "gimme-some-code-and-dont-bother-explaining" request. Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to apply the transition animation to the parent view that contains the animation of transitioning from one sub view to another.

```
UIView* view=[[UIView alloc]init];
UIView* parentView = self.view.superview;
[self.view removeFromSuperView];
[parentView addSubview:view];


CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self]; // set your delegate her to know when transition ended

[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight]; // set direction as you need

[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[parentView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"viewPush"];
```

You may need to further tweak this code to work in your situation of class design, etc.

Comment: ok... but i don't want to put @"flipping view" what else i can write here

Comment: I am not really sure what your question is then. If you want to do a transition animation from one view to another, this is how you do it.

Comment: i want to mimic UINavigation animation behavior when transitioning between two uiview.